# Pesquisa banco de dados vários itens PHP

Tags: php, firebird

Estou com o seguinte problema em `PHP`, estou fazendo uma pesquisa em um banco `Firebird` para que seja possível emitir um relatório com os pedidos de venda.

Irei entrar com os ID dos pedidos um a um e irão me retornar os valores. Porém, cada vez que faço a pesquisa ele elimina os dados já existentes, ficando somente o último valor pesquisado.

```
<?php
$a = $_GET['a'];
if($a == "buscar"){
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $sql = ibase_query("SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE LIKE '%".$id."%'");
     $row = ibase_fetch_row($sql);
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $id . '</td>';
     echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar ? (nas `Queries` está buscando o nome do cliente somente como exemplo, depois irei alterar para os dados do pedido, assim fica mais fácil visualizar)

Comment: Não tenho certeza mas acho que LIKE não funciona em tipo de dados INTEIRO. Tente usar
    "SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE =".$id

Comment: Entao, ele está buscando os dados conforme eu estou solicitando normalmente. Acho q nao formulei bem a pergunta. A questao é que quando faço uma nova pesquisa, ele deveria manter a primeira e exibir + a segunda, mas ele substitui os dados da primeira pela segunda, ficando somente uma linha

Comment: Oque você está recebendo em $_POST['id']? não seria $_GET['id'] ?

Comment: Não está clara a pergunta. O que é fazer uma nova pesquisa? Recarregar esse PHP no browser? Se for isso, limpar a tela é o comportamento esperado.

Comment: Concordo a pergunta ficou um pouco confusa, acho que vou fechar o topico, obrigado a quem ajudou!

Answer (score -1):

`ibase_fecth_row` só retorna uma linha por vez. Se você quiser mais de uma, você pode colocar a chamada de `ibase_fetch_row` em um laço de repetição, para percorrer todo o resultset. Fica mais ou menos assim

```
//........
$sql = ibase_query("SELECT NOME FROM TB_CLIENTE WHERE ID_CLIENTE LIKE '%".$id."%'");
     while($row = ibase_fetch_row($sql)){
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>' . $row[0] . '</td>';
     echo '<td>' . $id . '</td>';

     echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Na verdade, eu vou buscar um dado por vez, por exemplo, digita o id do primeiro usuario, ele busca e exibe, o segundo, busca exibe em baixo e assim por diante, entende ?